# Is it possible to calculate VSIZE of all columns within a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to calculate the VSIZE of all columns within a table to return a single aggregate value, without having to explicitly state each column name in the SQL statement?
So, a more efficient way to achieve what the following script does:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VSIZE(COLUMN_1)) "TOTAL BYTES COL 1" 
   ,SUM(VSIZE(COLUMN_2)) "TOTAL BYTES COL 2" 
   ,SUM(VSIZE(COLUMN_3)) "TOTAL BYTES COL 3" 
    ...
   ,SUM(VSIZE(COLUMN_n)) "TOTAL BYTES COL n" 
 FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

So, rather than returning an output that looks like this:

| TOTAL BYTES COL 1 | TOTAL BYTES COL 2 | TOTAL BYTES COL 3 | … | TOTAL BYTES COL n |
| 237437834748 | 376748438 | 35543643 | ... | 64648729 |

Instead returning an output like this:

| TOTAL BYTES ALL COLUMNS |

|  656393865939 |

I’m working with some tables that have in the region of 200 columns, so curious to learn if there’s a better way to achieve the above without the faff of having to e.g. export all the column names into a list, concatenate into a SQL statement, then export the results out and sum all the column totals to get the total.

Comment: I do not think what you are asking is truly useful. Better query user_segments or sys.dba_segments to see how much space a table actually takes. There is also the package dbms_space which is t be used to calculate the space allocated to a table which is not actually used by data. Thus, the sum of space from sys.dba_segments minus what is given as unused space by the procedure in dbms_space will give you how much space your data actually takes.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu - I don't entirely disagree with you. However, what I'm looking to create is a measure for quantifying the amount of data that will be deleted from tables as part of a compliance initiative, rather than to quantify how much tablespace has been freed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 11g? If it were higher version, you could do it (in a simple manner) in SQL, using a CTE that contains a function. In 11g, create function itself; it accepts table name as a parameter, then dynamically calculates result.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_size (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     l_size  NUMBER;
  5     retval  NUMBER := 0;
  6  BEGIN
  7     FOR cur_r
  8        IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
  9              FROM user_tab_columns
 10             WHERE table_name = DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name))
 11     LOOP
 12        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'select sum(vsize('
 13                         || cur_r.column_name
 14                         || ')) from '
 15                         || cur_r.table_name
 16           INTO l_size;
 17
 18        retval := retval + l_size;
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     RETURN retval;
 22  END f_size;
 23  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> SELECT f_size ('DEPT') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
        68
```

Is `68` correct?

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> SELECT SUM (VSIZE (deptno)) size_deptno,
  2         SUM (VSIZE (dname)) size_dname,
  3         SUM (VSIZE (loc)) size_loc
  4    FROM dept;

SIZE_DEPTNO SIZE_DNAME   SIZE_LOC
----------- ---------- ----------
          8         33         27

SQL> SELECT 8 + 33 + 27 AS result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
        68

SQL>
```

Right; `68` seems to be OK.

---

A CTE option (for future reference):

```
WITH
   FUNCTION f_size (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      l_size  NUMBER;
      retval  NUMBER := 0;
   BEGIN
      FOR cur_r IN (SELECT column_name
                      FROM user_tab_columns
                     WHERE table_name = par_table_name)
      LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'select sum(vsize('
                          || cur_r.column_name
                          || ')) from '
                          || par_table_name
            INTO l_size;
         retval := retval + l_size;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN retval;
   END f_size;
SELECT f_size ('DEPT') result
  FROM DUAL;
```

---

**[EDIT]** If you want to *analyze* other users' tables, you have to have appropriate privileges and - instead of `user_tab_columns` - access `all_tab_columns` (if you can query `dba_tab_columns`, you'd be able to fetch data for the whole database!).

Code slightly differs: function gets another parameter (`par_owner` which is used in cursor's `WHERE` clause).

Connected as `mike`, I'll create a new table and grant `select` privilege to `scott`:
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> create table test_scott as
2    select 1 id, 'Littlefoot' name from dual;

```
Table created.

SQL> grant select on test_scott to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connected as `scott`, I'm re-creating the function:

```
SQL> connect scott@pdb1
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_size (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2, par_owner IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     l_size  NUMBER;
  5     retval  NUMBER := 0;
  6  BEGIN
  7     FOR cur_r
  8        IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
  9              FROM all_tab_columns
 10             WHERE owner = par_owner
 11               AND table_name = DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name))
 12     LOOP
 13        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'select sum(vsize('
 14                         || cur_r.column_name
 15                         || ')) from '
 16                         || cur_r.table_name
 17           INTO l_size;
 18        retval := retval + l_size;
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     RETURN retval;
 22  END f_size;
 23  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_size('TEST', 'MIKE') result FROM dual;

    RESULT
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Comment: that works great for me, thanks. Is it possible to modify this function so that it can access tables in other schemas? I've experimented with modifying the function to accept an additional parameter for 'owner', and also tried hard-coding in the schema name within the WHERE clause - but without success.

Comment: You're welcome. I modified code so that it sees other users' data. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: Grateful for your work on this. I'm afraid though that I get no success with this; it always returns a result of '0' when I use against other schemas I have select privilege for - and also even when I specify my user schema as the owner input.

Answer (score 2):

you can look into the ALL_Tab_COLS table ,generate a SQL dynamically  and use that to get the sum, check the following example where i have created a 2 column table and i am generating a select SQL.

```
create table t1_tmp (fld1 integer, fld2 integer);

insert into t1_tmp values(10,23);
insert into t1_tmp values(14,24);
insert into t1_tmp values(24,14);

select sum(fld1) , sum(fld2) , (sum(fld1) + sum(fld2)) as total from t1_tmp;
select column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1_TMP';
SELECT ' SELECT  SUM(' || LISTAGG(column_name, ') + SUM(') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table_name)   || ')  FROM' "SUM_COLS"
FROM all_tab_cols  where table_name = 'T1_TMP';
```